# How to run web map application, that creates picture tiles, without storing cache in browser?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, web, dictionary, tile

I have a web map application, which has a lot of layers, that created as tiles in png format. My problem is when the app runs through updates, client browser has image cache, and map does not look like updated at some areas. How can I stop client browser to store cache for the app?

Comment: Do you have an app manifest in your web application? Can you check what headers the server is sending to the client?

Comment: No. I do not have manifest. This is asp app. What can I do about manifest that will be helpful for me?